# how to get the list of files from a merge commit id

Tags: git, git-log

I am in master branch, I need to get the list of files in each commit id, I am not able to retrieve any files using the merge commit id, If a merge happens from a different branch to master, then if use the regular (`git show` or `git diff tree`) for the merge commit id it returns nothing.

Basically I am not able to get the list of files that has been modified in different branch and merged to master. Is there a way to get the list of files using merge commit id ..??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
git log -m -1 --name-only --pretty="format:"  COMMITID
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what exactly I was looking, the command works just fine by retrieving all the files  in a merge commit id..Thanks..!!